# Change parent div background color when hovering text

Tags: html, css, animation

I've seen some *similar* posts about this but not one that seems to answer this question.

In an effort to learn CSS animations, I'm trying to do a 100% CSS verion of [this site](http://www.everydayim.com/).

The snag I've hit is that I can make it do the "rainbow animation when I hover over the "whitey" div, but I want it to only do this when I hover over the word "rainbow." Is there a way I can set the "whitey" div to 0 opacity while hovering over the text?

```css
#bg {
   /*BASIC DIV STYLING*/
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    font-size:50px;
    line-height:250px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    
    /*ANIMATION INFORMATION*/
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

/*DISPLAY CONTENT ON A WHITE BACKGROUND*/
.whitey {
  background-color:white;
  width:500px;height:250px;
}
/*MAKE THE WHITE BACKGROUND DISAPPEAR ON HOVER*/
.whitey:hover{
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  
/*THE ANIMATION*/
@keyframes example {
0% {background-color: #ff0000;}
10% {background-color: #ff8000;}
20% {background-color: #ffff00;}
30% {background-color: #80ff00;}
40% {background-color: #00ff00;}
50% {background-color: #00ff80;}
60% {background-color: #00ffff;}
70% {background-color: #0080ff;}
80% {background-color: #0000ff;}
90% {background-color: #8000ff;}
100% {background-color: #ff0080;}
}
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">

<div class="whitey">

<p>
RAINBOW
</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: lol, what is the point of that site!?

Comment: @alphapilgrim You don't visit that site every day like the rest of us?

Comment: I'm sure some kid probably created it as a project for school or something. While the site itself isn't very "useful" it does show some basic JS and JQ skill. What I'm trying to do is learn how parent/children/sibling elements work together when doing an animation. I figure if I can get this to work, I can probably figure out more complicated things later on. (EDIT: ON not NO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using JS you the background needs to be a child or sibling element of the the element you want to initiate the animation. In your case an element with some text.

#### Non-Preferred Solution

There's a couple ways to get the background animation element as a child element of the text element.

1. Nest an element: `<h1>Rainbow<div class="rainbow"></div></h1>` or
2. Create a pseudo element with CSS on the text element.

The way you get the child element *"out"* of the parent element is through absolute positioning. That will stretch the element out to the edges of the next positioned ancestor element.

```css
.rainbow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/* or */
h1:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;        
}
```

The issue with using some form of child element is that if you need to position the parent text element then the background doesn't get stretched out like you'd like it to. The parent text element's positioning would create a new context for the absolute positioned child background element to be confined in.

**Update:** You can use [`position: fixed;`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning) though other `position` values will not work. Thanks for @Green and our discussion on his answer for this update. This [will not work properly either](https://jsfiddle.net/xjbdjgtm/3/) if you used `translate` on the text element and `position: fixed;` on the animated background element.

#### Preferred Solution (Updated)

** Updated so that animation does not get restarted on each hide/show.*

So I suggest using a sibling element approach. This will allow you to position the text element without confining the background element, i.e. the center of an element/page.

As your example page uses an element to hide/show the animated background, so can you. Apply the animation right away and use the sibling selector to hide/show the element that hides/shows the animated background.

```html
<h1>Rainbow</h1>
<div class="lid"></div>
<div class="rainbow"></div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
}
.lid,
.rainbow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.lid {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
.rainbow {  
  animation-name: rainbow;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  z-index: -2;
}
h1:hover + .lid {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0%   { background-color: #ff0000; }
  10%  { background-color: #ff8000; }
  20%  { background-color: #ffff00; }
  30%  { background-color: #80ff00; }
  40%  { background-color: #00ff00; }
  50%  { background-color: #00ff80; }
  60%  { background-color: #00ffff; }
  70%  { background-color: #0080ff; }
  80%  { background-color: #0000ff; }
  90%  { background-color: #8000ff; }
  100% { background-color: #ff0080; }
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6rd0j8n/2/), updated.

- [Sibling Selector Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2)

In both solutions you'd need an ancestor element that fills the whole viewport so your absolute positioned background element does as well.

Comment: I came up with a similar solution earlier on. Is there a way to "keep it running" when I'm not hovering over the words? As it is, this code will start the animation over from the beginning at every mouseover.

EDIT: 
In my snippet, the advantage to what I was doing was that the animation continually looped in the background even when not hovering. Is there any way to emulate that with this format that you've written?

Comment: Yes, create an additional element to hide the animated background. Instead of using the sibling selector to hide show the animated background use it to hide/show the background that is used to hide/show the animated background, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6rd0j8n/2/).

Comment: The updated Fiddle was what I was looking for. Time to study it and internalize it so I can git gud with my animation skills.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjbdjgtm/).

Just use:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

And `:before` or `:after`.

Create pseudo-element, position it relative to root/viewport and resize to viewport/site width and height. Then apply any other style you want.

It's a clean and pretty solution. At least I think so.

Comment: Please clarify what `pointer-events` has to do with your solution. It works without it. As I noted in my answer, how would you deal with a position element when using pseudo elements?

Comment: It makes sure that no pointer events will be handled with pseudo-element and I don't really understand second question. Pseudo element (in this case) is not positioned relative to anything but viewport and has width and height of it. If you want to be sure just use `position: fixed` and that will be 100% relative to viewport.

Comment: @hungerstar And no, it doesn't work without it; with some browsers and good mouse handling you could hold hover.

Comment: It works in my desktop browsers and Galaxy S6 without the `pointer-events` property. Here is an [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjbdjgtm/2/) with no pointer events and a positioned text element.

Comment: @hungerstar Fiddle you have sent doesn't work properly on my desktop and it won't work well because according to standards of `position` property it won't place pseudo-element correctly.

Comment: That's the point of that [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjbdjgtm/2/). The two points being made are: **1.** That the animation continues to work on desktop and mobile (well, at least on my Galaxy S6) without `point-events` property. **2.** That when the parent text element is positioned (`position` property is set on it) that the background animation itself is not positioned as intended (taking up viewport background) and is positioned relative to the positioned parent text element. Your solution does indeed work but with some caveats.

Comment: @hungerstar *just use `position: fixed` and that will be 100% relative to viewport.* – *Green 1 hour ago*. What's the point of this discussion? It works. That's all. With some basic knowledge you can avoid every flaw of it.

Comment: Your suggestions are not working or are incorrect. I just tried `position: fixed;` and does not fix the animated background's position. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjbdjgtm/3/) with `fixed` applied to pseudo element. I'm trying to see what I'm missing so I can possibly learn something I didn't know before.

Comment: @hungerstar `translate`... [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qe6zgunv/) (no `pointer-events`, because you have deleted them) (also it was obvious what caused problem, because it was last rule you have edited).

Comment: Ah, `translate` was the culprit. Very nice. That's what I was looking for. Thanks for sticking with me. Although I'm not clear on why `translate` causes that issue. I'm guessing it is being inherited/applied to the child pseudo element?

Comment: @hungerstar No problem. It's probably the bug in the renderer caused by `translate` used with `position: fixed`. I will check later how it works with normal child. According to [W3 CSS Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) it should be placed relative to viewport.